# Derivation of Rarita-Schwinger Spin-3/2 Spinor Completeness Relation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors

Given the explicit wave functions of the Rarita-Schwinger spin-3/2 field

$$
\begin{align}
U^\mu_{3/2} &=\epsilon^\mu_{+1} u_{1/2}\\
U^\mu_{1/2} &=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\epsilon^\mu_{+1} u_{-1/2}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\epsilon^\mu_0 u_{1/2}\\
U^\mu_{-1/2} &=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\epsilon^\mu_0 u_{-1/2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\epsilon^\mu_{-1} u_{1/2}\\
U^\mu_{-3/2} &=\epsilon^\mu_{-1} u_{-1/2}
\end{align}
$$

How do I calculate
$$\Xi^{\mu\nu} = \sum_m U^\mu_m \overline{U}^\nu_m\quad?$$

The solution looks like

$$(\rlap{/}{p}+m)\left[-\eta^{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{3}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\frac{2}{3}\frac{p^\mu p^\nu}{p^2}-\frac{p^\mu\gamma^\nu-p^\nu\gamma^\mu}{3m}\right]$$

and could be obtained by constructing the projection operators via the Pauli-Lubanski formalism. However, I'm looking for a different way.

Can you do it just knowing that

$$\sum_s u_s \overline{u}_s = \rlap{/}{p}+m$$

and

$$\sum_\lambda \epsilon_\lambda^\mu \overline\epsilon_\lambda^\nu = -\eta^{\mu\nu} + \frac{p^\mu p^\nu}{p^2}$$

(Convention: $\eta_{\mu\nu} = \text{diag}\left(1,-1,-1,-1\right)_{\mu\nu}$)